# Best way to run background logic with Riverpod providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a a StreamProvider that exposes the User. I want to run logic in the background based on the provider. I **don't** want to consume the providers in my Widget tree. I'm interested in:

- Where to initialise the logic - is `main.dart` appropriate?
- If the logic isn't related to a ConsumerWidget, where would I access my `WidgetRef`?
- How should I encapsulate my logic? Ie: Which classes or methods should I use?

```dart
final currentUserProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref){
  return CurrentUserStream(); // The details don't matter
});
```

Below I have a couple of simplified use-cases.

### Use-Case 1: Apply my userId somewhere

I want to make sure the userId is used for my analytics service

```dart
final User? user = ref.watch(currentUserProvider);
if (user != null) {
  // Update analytics to track the userId
}
```

### Use-Case 2: Manage Streams for the user

In this case, it's critical that I have a `dispose` method to tidy up after the user changes. This would be triggered if the user logs out / switches account.

```dart
final User? user = ref.watch(currentUserProvider);

/// Streams related to the user
List<StreamSubscription> userStreamSubscriptions;
if (user != null) {
  // The details don't matter
}

/// Cancels the user Streams when the user changes
@override
void dispose() {
  for (var subscription in userStreamSubscriptions) {
    subscription.cancel();
  }
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: It's a very specific question that needs more info to answer. You can ask in more generalised way then we can get idea

Comment: @nitishk72 I've updated my question to be more generalised. I hope it makes sense (if not, I'll update again!)

Comment: Stop using the provider then. Provider is only used for state management. If you do not need to manage state, for instance, for the user, make it global and check for it whenever you like. That's just my take on it. You can update the user from anywhere then with no need for provider. You can make a singleton for it as well for quick access. If you still need to use the provider, make the provider update the user and access it anyway you like.

Comment: @Ariel that seems reasonable. What I want from riverpod are the computed states. ie: I can chain together multiple streams and notifiers without having to do things like `Rx.combineLatestX` or Stream `switchMap`. It makes the logic very readable. I have logic like Config relates to Company relates to User relates to Auth. Since Riverpod is handling that for UI, it makes sense to include it for background logic. Things like "the user has promised to upload these files to this company" is something I want to do in the BG, but also have an interface for, if the user decides to take a peek.

Comment: @oodavid did you figure out a way to use riverpod for this?

Answer (score -1):

I don`t know can that help you and will actual for you, but anyway after little research I understand one way. For background logic I was used ConsumerStatefulWidget with his state. In state class we need declare login in initState method, because the state class have a ref field.
My example app (plus flutter_hooks, but not a lot) https://github.com/nicourrrn/flutter-state-managment